# How to copy note from Sales Order to Shipment Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

How can I copy the note from a SalesOrder to a Shipment as the shipment is created?

I am trying to use the PXNoteAttribute.GetNote()/PXNoteAttribute.SetNote() functions, but GetNote keeps turning up blank.

```
#region Event Handlers
```

string notetext;

```
protected void SOShipLine_RowInserted(PXCache cache, PXRowInsertedEventArgs e, PXRowInserted InvokeBaseHandler)
{
  if(InvokeBaseHandler != null)
    InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);
  var row = (SOShipLine)e.Row;
  SOOrder SalesOrder = (SOOrder)PXSelectorAttribute.Select<SOShipLine.origOrderNbr>(cache, e.Row);
  string note = PXNoteAttribute.GetNote(cache, SalesOrder);
  notetext = note;
}

protected void SOShipment_RowUpdated(PXCache cache, PXRowUpdatedEventArgs e, PXRowUpdated InvokeBaseHandler)
{
  if(InvokeBaseHandler != null)
    InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);
  var row = (SOShipment)e.Row;
  PXNoteAttribute.SetNote(cache, cache.Current, notetext);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cache you are referencing in your code is the cache for the ShipLine. You need to reference the SalesOrder cache for GetNote() to function properly. You can use Base.Caches[typeof(SOOrder)].

Like so:

```
 #region Event Handlers
string notetext;

protected void SOShipLine_RowInserted(PXCache cache, PXRowInsertedEventArgs e, PXRowInserted InvokeBaseHandler)
{
  if(InvokeBaseHandler != null)
    InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);
  var row = (SOShipLine)e.Row;
  SOOrder SalesOrder = (SOOrder)PXSelectorAttribute.Select<SOShipLine.origOrderNbr>(cache, e.Row);
  string note = PXNoteAttribute.GetNote(Base.Caches[typeof(SOOrder)], SalesOrder);
  notetext = note;
}

protected void SOShipment_RowUpdated(PXCache cache, PXRowUpdatedEventArgs e, PXRowUpdated InvokeBaseHandler)
{
  if(InvokeBaseHandler != null)
    InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);
  var row = (SOShipment)e.Row;
  PXNoteAttribute.SetNote(cache, cache.Current, notetext);
```

}

Comment: This link helped me get this answer. Shout out to this post in Russian.
https://reddeveloper.ru/questions/okno-zametok-ne-obnovlyayet-sya-dlya-scheta-dRmg7